# Virtualization in Linux

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I run XP as a virtual machine with this hardware spec ?](https://superuser.com/questions/17633/can-i-run-xp-as-a-virtual-machine-with-this-hardware-spec)

Does it require too much RAM if i have to run windows on linux.
Currently I have 512+128 MB DDR ram.
I want to run XP on Suse

Comment: Defined "too much". How much RAM do you have? What else will you be doing on that machine? What will that Windows be doing?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Also, which release of Windows will you be running? Vista will require a lot more memory than XP.

Comment: I had a similar question. The answers might be relevant for you: http://superuser.com/questions/17633/can-i-run-xp-as-a-virtual-machine-with-this-hardware-spec

Comment: @Nagul: I'd say it's a dupe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may require as low as 128MB or as much as 4+GB. It depends of use of the box. If you want to play Solitaire on Windows, probably it should be enough about additional 256MB of RAM (I think that virtualized graphic card also uses system memory).